# How to add SQLite rows to an ArrayList<>

Tags: android, sqlite, arraylist

I retrieve all the rows from my SQLite-DB Table

```
Cursor  cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from table",null);
```

Then I want to add each row to an `ArrayList`

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IF you're using custom object array, then use like following :

```
public void fillDataToArray() {

            ArrayList<BeanClass> arrayList = new ArrayList<BeanClass>();
            DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getActivity());
            db.open();
            try
        {
            Cursor c = db.getImageNameForList();

                if (c != null && c.getCount() > 0) {
                c.moveToFirst();
                for (int count = 0; count < c.getCount(); count++) {
                     Beanclass detail = new Beanclass ();

                     detail.setName(c.getString(c
                     .getColumnIndex(DatabaseHandler._ID)));

                     detail.setPath(c.getString(c
                     .getColumnIndexOrThrow(DatabaseHandler._PATH)));

                     arrayList.add(detail);
                    c.moveToNext();

                    }
                }
        }
    catch(Exception e)
        {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
            c.close();
            db.close();

        }
```

If you use this in activity, change `getActivity()` to local context or whichever way you use context in activities.

**DATA RETRIEVAL METHOD IN DB ADAPTER CLASS :**

```
> public Cursor getImageNameForList() {         
return db.rawQuery("select " + IMAGE_PATH + " from "+ TABLE_PRODUCT_IMAGES , null);     
}
```

Comment: If I want to display "Image ID" of 2nd item in ArrayList<BeanClass> in a TextView how would I do that please? I can create the xml layout I just want the JAVA part.

Comment: textView.setText(arrayList.get(1).getImageID().toString());  Here "1" is the position/index of the second item of arraylist.

Answer (score 2):

Code to do that would look like this, depending on whats in your Table. You have to create a Class that is able to represent a Row in your table.

For example if there are people in your table, with name and age, you will need an object Human(String name, int age) to put into a list.

```
SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getReadableDatabase();
ArrayList<Human> results = new ArrayList<Human>();

try {

    String rawQuery = "Select name, age from people";

    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(rawQuery, null);

    try {

        if (!c.moveToFirst())
            return null;

        do {
            results.add(new Human(c.getString(0),c.getInt(1)));
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    } finally {
        c.close();
    }
} finally {
    db.close();
}



public class Human {
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public Human (String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more on Human, Name, Age example please, and adapt it to the solution above.

Comment: @eMM done, udated the code and provided the Human class as well as a proper sql query

Comment: Creative solution Daniel. +1

Answer (score 0):

In your Db Adapter class, add this method

```
public ArrayList<String>getData()
{
    ArrayList<String>names=new ArrayList<String>();
    Cursor c = getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("Select * from tableName", null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    do
    {
        String s1=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("<Column_Name>"));
        names.add(s1);
    }while(c.moveToNext());     
    return names;
}
```

after that in your activity class add this

```
ArrayList<String> cid;
DB_Adapter database = new DB_Adapter(getApplicationContext(), "<your schema name>", null, 1);
cid=database.getData();
```

After that add your arraylist to your array adapter which is set to ListView

Comment: What is "<your schema name>" please?

Comment: it is the name of your database, you can give any name you want.